# Let $a,b,c,d$ be real numbers such that $a<b < c<d$. Express the set $[a,b] \cup [c,d]$ as the difference of two sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, formal-proofs

I am not sure how I would express these sets as a difference. My original attempt was to show that it is the set $[a,d]$ and take away the universal set. I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you take the universal set away from anything, you would be left with nothing.  Perhaps you should take away something smaller

Comment: What about $[a,d]-[b,c]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can take
$$[a,d]-(b,c).$$
This basically takes all the numbers from $a$ to $d$, including the two, and then removes the numbers from $b$ to $c$, not including $b$ and $c$.

Answer (score 0):

Universal set is too big to be taken away.Try this-

$$[a,d]-(b,c)$$

Comment: That would not have $b$ or $c$ so that would be $[a,b) \cup (c,d]$.